# Organising and examining a complicated CSV file

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, csv-format

I am being sent data in CSV files. The sender is providing helpful comments and lots of headings so that it is fine to look at in a spreadsheet environment. However, when I import it into Mathematica it becomes difficult to read using  `TableForm` mostly because many of the cells contain comments that are very long.

How do I restrict the length of `TableForm` entries?

Here is a minimum working example of the results of using `Import[]` on the CSV file.

```
ip = {{{"", "", ""}, {"", "", ""}, {"", 
     "Data for tests on the 14th April 2021", ""}, {"", "", ""}, {"", 
     "Here is a very long line. Only the start of the line needs to \
be seen since an overview of the spreadsheet is required. ", ""}, {"",
      "", ""}, {"", 
     "The data is in 4 four sheets this sheet is the summary", 
     ""}, {"", "", ""}, {"", "Start ", "End"}, {"Data 1", 2.`, 
     5.`}, {"Data 2", 5.`, 9.`}, {"Data 3", 20.`, 25.`}, {"Data 4", 
     12.`, 17.`}}, {{"x vals", "y vals"}, {2.`, 
     0.3330287479237922`}, {3.`, 0.19273318644865778`}, {4.`, 
     0.2689069410951601`}, {5.`, 0.08207429250157161`}}, {{"x vals", 
     "y vals"}, {5.`, 0.45418961829920845`}, {6.`, 
     0.571585992020961`}, {7.`, 0.2085062721975699`}, {8.`, 
     0.4228854382612791`}, {9.`, 0.8204853099017002`}}, {{"x vals", 
     "y vals"}, {20.`, 0.004555883050753273`}, {21.`, 
     0.9461665188994238`}, {22.`, 0.5266492863708679`}, {23.`, 
     0.993247994762222`}, {24.`, 0.40219540885589733`}, {25.`, 
     0.7634085960638198`}}, {{"x vals", "y vals"}, {12.`, 
     0.15418438184183136`}, {13.`, 0.6223264477185402`}, {14.`, 
     0.9009276274909394`}, {15.`, 0.6832380927198871`}, {16.`, 
     0.16021536248120283`}, {17.`, 0.27399014026061996`}}};
Dimensions[ip]
```

The `Dimensions[]` tells me that there are 5 sheets. So I look at the first sheet using `TableForm`.

```
TableForm[ip[[1]], TableSpacing -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Image of output]

As you can see the long comments in some CSV cells make some entries in the table much longer than others. I just want an overview of the contents so I don't want to see all the details in each entry. I probably need to do some form of converting to strings and then limiting the number of characters in each string.  I am sure there are other possibilities as well. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this? The following function will divide the available screen width into equally sized columns and then uses scrollbars to display content when it becomes too tall:

```
readableGrid[content_List, maxRowHeight : _ : 50, gridOpts : OptionsPattern[]] := Grid[
  Map[
   Pane[#, ImageSize -> {Full, UpTo[maxRowHeight]}, 
     Scrollbars -> {False, Automatic}, AppearanceElements -> None] &,
   content,
   {2}
   ],
  gridOpts,
  ItemSize -> Scaled[0.99/Max[Length /@ content]],
  Alignment -> Left
  ]
TabView[readableGrid /@ ip]
```

Alternatively, you can use `ImageSize -> {UpTo[200], UpTo[maxRowHeight]}` (or however wide you want your columns to be at most) in the `Pane` and leave out the `ItemSize` option in `Grid`. You can similarly also put a `Pane` with a scrollbar around the whole `Grid` to make sure the output cell itself remains manageable in size.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd lots to learn from in your post. I was hoping for something more simple like an option to `TableForm` but as you have shown these things are never so straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Grid` and selecting text to display

```
grid[data_] := Grid[data, Background -> {None, 1 -> LightYellow}, Dividers -> Center]

heading = (ip[[1, 1 ;; 8]] // Map[Select[# != "" &]]) //. {} -> Nothing // Flatten // First

Grid[{{heading, SpanFromLeft},
  {grid@ip[[1, 9 ;;]], Splice@Table[grid[ip[[i]]], {i, 2, Length@ip}]}},
 Alignment -> Top,
 Frame -> All,
 ItemStyle -> {Automatic, 1 -> {Bold}}]
```

[image]

Could add a header to each of the sub-grids, "Summary", "Sheet 1", etc.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Dropping rows from the data is one solution.